# How to avoid right "padding" for ragged-right content

Tags: html, css

I have the following code snippet, which results in an unwanted "padding" zone, while padding is zero. How can this zone be avoided?

### Code

```css
div.left {
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

div.right {
  background-color: aqua;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  longcontent longcontent longcontent 
</div>
<div class="right">
  something
</div>
```

### Result

[image: There is an unwanted zone in ragged-right divs]

### What I want

[image: Desired Result]

### Edit

The above snippet is over simplified. The solution should also work for more complex examples:

```css
div.left {
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 40%;
  float: left;
}
div.right {
  background-color: aqua;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  longcontent
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/snioV.png">
</div>
<div class="right">
  something
</div>
```

Comment: The code snippet you provided looks fine to me in Chrome

Comment: Try resizing it @WesFoster https://jsfiddle.net/zfvLboxm/

Comment: Aha, yeah. It's definitely due to the non-breaking string, but none of the white-space or box-sizing attributes would fix that as far as I know. Interesting scenario. I'll keep watch on this

Comment: you'd be better off to add an ellipsis.. see this link https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/

Answer (score 2):

If you really want, maybe try to add word-break: break-all; to left

```css
div.left {
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 25%;
  float: left;
  word-break: break-all;
}

div.right {
  background-color: aqua;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  longcontent longcontent longcontent 
</div>
<div class="right">
  something
</div>
```

Comment: beware of using this,  you'll get broken words all over the place!!

Comment: @RachelGallen, yeah, your concern is definitely right. Is there any safer way for doing this?

Comment: see my comment above.. far safer using ellipsis if overflow is a concern

Comment: This seems to work for my simplified example snippet. But in reality the content contains images which aren't affected by ``word-break``.

Comment: but yeah if you do nowrap on whitespace yer kinda screwed

Comment: @RachelGallen, as this simple example snippet and requirement, I don't think ellipsis works for it. What I provide above is just a "bad code manner" but meet the requirement for this simple snippet. But thanks a lot for figuring this out! :)

Comment: @Waog, In order to get to a better solution, you may need to provide more detail part of your examples.

Comment: @RachelGallen possibly. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @KelvinYe but it's like he said, in reality, the div would contain images etc that wouldn't be affected by word break. Really a show/hide approach is the best if he's gonna have paragraphs with lots of text in them

Comment: @RachelGallen, Agreed!

Comment: @Waog something like this https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/suvfqk0a/ its much better if you have paragraphs with lots of text and images

Comment: @Waog you can put loads of them in one page and save a whole load of space. I was against this particular page but the client insisted - see http://musicmatters.ie/team.html